# One-to-many SQL JOIN produces a lot of copies of the same "one", is this a good practice?

Tags: mysql, join

I need to make a one-to-many joined SQL query, like select all orders for all customers.

One customer can have many orders.

```
SELECT
  C.firstName,
  C.lastName,
  O.invoiceID,
  O.description
FROM Customers AS C
LEFT JOIN Orders AS O
  ON Customers.ID = Orders.CustomerID
```

Every returned row will contain a copy of customer's name, with different order data.

I do need to have customers' names in the result, but I'm not sure if it's OK to have the names unnecessarily copied in every row. Is this a waste of memory? Should I better only include Customer ID in the joined select, and then make a separate select to get the customer names by customer ids? What is the best practice?

**Update:** I understand the tradeoffs and that it depends. My question is whether there are some internal DBMS or driver optimizations (in the most popular DBMS'es) which prevent unnecessary memory waste in such joined selects, by sharing memory for the repeated fields.

Comment: I'm voting to close, because 'it depends'. It does take up more memory and perhaps more network traffic, but it depends on the number of fields you get from customer and how large they are, and moreover it depends on how many orders a customer has. If it's 1 or 2, there is hardly any overhead. If you have just a few customers but each with a million orders, the overhead is huge. Also note that separate queries require separate roundtrips, parsing and other overhead. Some sweetspot? Probably. Fixed rules? No.

Comment: What actual output do you want to see?  Let this determine what your query will look like.

Comment: it depends on a lot of aspects... you have to check you use case and see what is better. For example (but not exclusively to this example, for sure there are others aspects), if only a hundred of rows, it may be ok. If you have millions, you may have to rethink your approach.

Comment: See my update. I understand the tradeoffs and that it depends. My question is whether there are some internal DBMS or driver optimizations (in the most popular DBMS'es) which prevent unnecessary memory waste in such joined selects, by sharing memory for the repeated fields.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the memory consumption. I think the main tradeoff is between network traffic and the overhead of multiple executions. But even that depends on your tech stack, the moon phase, and a bunch of opinions. Personally, I would chose the format that suits me best, and try to limit the number of queries I execute to a handful, so when I want to get all customers/orders for the whole year, I would rather use this join, while if I get all orders for one customer, I would fetch the customer info separately.